# How to control what appears on google search results?

Tags: google, seo, sitemap, robots.txt

So I have just built a site and all is well... but I want to control what appears on google search results.

Lets say I google for "thefwa", first what comes is the link to www.thefwa.com, then underneath is a list of pages on that site with preview and  a link "More results from thefwa.com".
How can I tell google to display my chosen content/pages? Do I use robots.txt or sitemap.xml? Because now the pages that are associated with my site are displayed kind of random.

Is it possible to tell google what to display?

Comment: What's shown is relevant to what's queried for (and how)...so what you see might not be what everyone else sees - and not everyone searches for your "glory" terms. Don't fret. The best way you can influence this is through good internal linking, site architecture, clear titles and content definition.

Answer (score 1):

The only control you have for the sitelinks section is to demote items to move them down in preference. Google chooses these items for display, demoting may remove them from the list depending on Google's choice. Demotion lasts for 90 days.

You need to set up a Google Webmaster Tools account. Once you do this, you can look in the lefthand menu for **Site Configuration -> Sitelinks**. [More information on sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=47334)

Comment: I don't think they're talking about sitelinks but the "More results from thefwa.com" link that shows results from their site when clicked.

Comment: @JohnConde That's possible, though his description sounds like an initial link, sitelinks and the more results link that shows when you type in your company name for your well established company. And when I type in "thefwa", that's what I get, so I figured he was referring to the sitelinks in his example. If he's referring to the "More Results link" then it's Google's call alone.