# How to get google to show certain subpages

Tags: seo, google

Is there a way in which I can tell Google which of my navigation items I consider most important and that I would like to have displayed underneath my "main search result" in Search? E.g., if B&H wanted to have their *login page* among the six that I have circled in the image below, could they influence that in some way?

[image: image of search results]

Answer (score 2):

No. You can only demote sitelinks (ask Google *not* to show them).

Google Webmaster Tools > Search Appearance > Sitelinks

Question already anwered here: [How to control what appears on google search results?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24218/how-to-control-what-appears-on-google-search-results)